# Unable to build Hello World application for Kindle Fire HDX tablet using PhoneGap 3.3.0

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-3

I'm using [PhoneGap 3.3.0](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_amazonfireos_index.md.html) along with the [Amazon WebView SDK](https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/IntegratingAWV.html) to attempt to build a "Hello World" application for my Kindle Fire 7" HDX tablet.

I have the Android 4.4.2, 4.2.2, and 2.2 SDKs installed. I have been able to successfully build, install, and run several PhoneGap applications on my Nexus 7 Android tablet as well as the Android emulator.

However the "amazon-fireos" build always fails with an *Unhandled 'error' event*.

I have searched Stack Overflow, the web, and the [PhoneGap Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/phonegap) but no one appears to have experienced the issue yet, possibly since Kindle Fire support is relatively new ([added 16 Dec 2013](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2013/12/16/cordova-330.html)).

```
$ cordova create hello com.example.hello "HelloWorld"

Creating a new cordova project with name "HelloWorld" and id "com.example.hello" at location "/Users/jack/phonegap/hello"

$ cd hello

$ cordova platform add amazon-fireos

Checking Amazon FireOS requirements...
Checking if awv_interface.jar exists... in framework/libs folder
Creating amazon-fireos project...
Preparing amazon-fireos project

$ cordova build

Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "amazon-fireos"
Preparing amazon-fireos project
Compiling app on platform "amazon-fireos" via command     "/Users/jack/phonegap/hello/platforms/amazon-fireos/cordova/build" 

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: spawn EACCES
    at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
```

It looks like someone was having a [similar problem](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4403) that ended up being an environment variable issue. There are only two jar files in the WebView SDK (awv_android_factory.jar and
awv_interface.jar). I tried adding both the path to the jar files to the PATH variable and both jars to the CLASSPATH, but it didn't appear to have any effect.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/jack/Downloads/awv_api
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/Users/jack/Downloads/awv_api/awv_interface.jar:/Users/jack/Downloads/awv_api/awv_android_factory.jar:.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a permissions issue. Just execute :

chmod 777 path_to_your_sample/platforms/amazon-fireos/cordova/build

This should solve your problem.

Comment: chmod 755 path_to_your_sample/platforms/amazon-fireos/cordova/build solves the problem too.